# Is there any one-line analogy in ES6 for ES5 `module.exports = require('./inner.js')`?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
// before
module.exports = require('./inner.js');
// nowadays
export default from './inner.js';
```

i'm trying to do this, but babel allow it only in es7 stage 1 as it is [proposal for now](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from). So for now, im stick to these two lines:

```
import sticker from './box-sticker.jsx';
export default sticker;
```

Can I shorter them to one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
export {default as default} from './inner.js';
// or even
export {default} from './inner.js';
```

with current ES6 semantics.

However I don't think there's anything wrong with using the ES next proposal, I'm pretty confident that it will make it into <s>ES7</s> ES8.

Comment: That case can be shortened to `export {default} from './inner.js';`

Comment: @PhysRex Whether one can omit the file extension or not depends on the module  loader that resolves the name, but this has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Has this technique/pattern a well-known name?  
Is this the modern way of the "Module (Design) Pattern" ?

Comment: @Alex75 I don't see a particular pattern here