# How to export entire module as the default?

Tags: ecmascript-6

e.g.

```
// lib.js
export function f1() {}
export function f2() {}
export * as default; // invalid syntax
```

And then in another file:

```
// app.js
import lib from './lib.js';
lib.f1();
```

Is there a way to do this without exporting each function explicitly? e.g.

```
export default {f1, f2}; // tedious
```

PS: I am aware that I can `import * as lib from './lib.js'`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are already exporting them by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as lib from './lib';
export default lib;
```

should be enough. So the module imports all of its own exports and then exports itself as its default export.

I'll second Bergi's answer though, this isn't great from an API design standpoint, and will probably be slower. If something is using your module and needs to import from it, it should know what it's importing, or ask for them all on its own, your module shouldn't do it for them.

Comment: You can import yourself?? How does that not create a recursion bomb?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a problem, you're essentially grabbing a reference to the module's exports, before the exports have been initialized, but after they've all been parsed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that I can `import * as lib from './lib.js'`.

And you really should. Don't make your API more confusing than it needs to be.

If you still want to default-export your own module namespace object, you can also do

```
export * as default from "./lib.js"; // self-reference
```

Comment: That syntax is proposal, and also doesn't currently allow `default`, though I did file an issue to see if that was intentional: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-ns-from/issues/1

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Ah, I knew I should've checked before posting this. [I really should have known](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34072770/1048572).

Comment: How does this make my API more confusing? I'm not using `default` for anything else, it just saves you from writing `* as` every time you use the lib. 99% of the time you *want* the namespace, and if you don't for some reason, you still have that option.

Comment: "`* as`" is not that long, and makes clear what you are importing (to both the programmer and the engine which might have optimisations based on this). In contrast, having a namespace that contains itself is just… weird, in my eyes.

Comment: Think of a library like lodash. What would you expect `import _ from 'lodash'` to do? I'd say that's pretty clear it's giving me the typical lodash object; there is no other default that makes sense here, really. Optimizations... do you have any sources to back that up? Would it become un-tree-shakable if we export the full object as default?

Comment: If I were using lodash in ES6, I'd do `import {map, pluck, …} from "lodash";` anyway. As for optimisations, it doesn't become impossible, but it's an edge case that might not be considered in tree-shaking.

Answer (score 0):

heres another option:

lib.js

```
export default {
   someFunctionOne: () =>  {

   },

   someFunctionTwo: () =>  {

   },


   someFunctionThree: () =>  {

   }
};
```

app.js

```
import lib from './lib';

lib.someFunctionOne();
```

Comment: I wanted both the bare names and the default object though :)