# Export react jsx-components in index.js files

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I bundle react-components, defined in jsx-files, in an index.js file?

In a way that the components can be accessed by `import module from "/module"; let C = module.Component;`.

With:

```
/module
  index.js
  Component.jsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export Component from "./Component"
```

You should not use export default for your use case. There is only a single default export per module. This value is to be considered as the "main" exported value since it will be the simplest to import. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export for more detail

Comment: Thank you, but this is not my point here, the problem is that the index.js seems to be incompatible with the jsx files.

Comment: is the code working if you replace your import and export statement with my code?

Comment: Thank you! The `index.js` as proposed [here][1] is working:
`export { default as Component } from "./Component.jsx";`
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file

Answer (score 24):

To re-export the component as a default export:

```
export { default } from './Component';
```

To re-export the component as a named export:

```
export { default as NamedComponent } from './Component';
```

You should prefer exporting as default from `index.js` since it will likely be the only export from the index.

Your component import will look like this:

```
import Component from './module';
```

or this, if you use a named export:

```
import { NamedComponent } from './module';
```

Assuming you're using webpack to bundle your files, to make sure your imports can use `'./Component'` instead of `'./Component.jsx'`, include `.jsx` as an extension in your `resolve` property in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside index.js

export { default as ComponentName } from './Component';

Then In App.js [Import it Like this]

import {ComponentName} from './module'