# Confusing es6 import -> export statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is this valid javascript?  It does not error, and appears to work.

```
export {default as Chooser} from "./chooser";
```

My interpretation is:

1. `import` the `default` from `"./chooser"`
2. `export` the result from #1 `as Chooser`

Is this what is happening?

Comment: If it works, what's the question?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34072770/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this valid JavaScript?

Yes.

> Is this what is happening?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct.

> `import` the `default` from `"./chooser"`

This is correct. The default thing being exported is `Chooser` and on import, you *must* use the name given to it with `as ...`:

```
import { Chooser } from "./chooser";
```

> `export` the result from #1 as `Chooser`

This is also correct. The name `Chooser` is giving the default a new name and exporting it.

---

Let me break this down:

```
export {
    default as Chooser
} from "./chooser";
```

What this does is specify the file from which it is exported, and `default as Chooser` exports the default under the name `Chooser`. Now, on import:

```
import { Chooser } from "./chooser";
```

You must specify `Chooser` to import because you've essentially named the default.

Comment: Really? *This is also correct, but the module exports Chooser as default, and then on import, import finds the default export and imports it.* I think the module exports it under the name `Chooser`, and it must be imported as `import {Chooser} from './exports';`. If you want to re-export the default export, I think you need to say `export {default} from './chooser`;`. Also, what does `foo` in your answer refer to?

Comment: *"can be used globally as its the default thing being exported"* What does default exports have to do with "globally"? What does that mean in that context?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure *why* I put that in but it's removed. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @torazaburo I have edited the answer, thanks for the constructive criticism!