# JavaScript ecma 6 bulk import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working in ReactJS, I have a number of classes with the same imports:

```
import MyClass from './some/path/foo.js';
import MyClass2 from './some/path/bar.js';
```

Only the list is much longer. Can these classes just import one file that has all the imports (bulk import)?

Comment: Did you encounter any issues when you tried it?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34072598/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean you want to have an imports file an then link that file. There is sort of a way to to do this but not sure it gets all of what you need.

You'll create a file imports.js that has:

```
export * from './some/path/foo.js';
export * from './some/path/bar.js';
```

then you'll have your file that uses the imports do:

```
import { MyClass, MyClass2 ... } from './path/to/imports.js';
```