# Dynamically reference static ESNext imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next

Say I have these imports:

```
import clearLineReporter from '../modules/clear-line-reporter';
import karmaReporter from '../modules/karma-reporter';
import metaTestReporter from '../modules/meta-test-reporter';
import stdReporter from '../modules/std-reporter';
import tapJSONReporter from '../modules/tap-json-reporter';
import tapReporter from '../modules/tap-reporter';
import webSocketReporter from '../modules/websocket-reporter';
```

these must be referenced like I do above, in other words, I obviously can't do this:

```
const imports = {
     stdReporter: import(...),
     tapJSONReporter: import(...),
     ...
     webSocketReporter: import(...)
}
```

Is there any way I can reference imported files through some form of reflection? Because it seems like I can't group them together to reference them somehow.

Instead of import syntax, I could use `require()`, but I am wondering if there is some way I can do some dynamic things with import statements, for example reference them all dynamically, such that if I add or remove an import, I don't have to change any other code.

Comment: Consider creating an `index.js` file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072770/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722646/1048572), and then use `import * as imports from '../modules';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great answer to this question that I discovered by asking a different question, here:

[exporting imports as a namespace with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500855/exporting-imports-as-a-namespace-with-typescript)

Create a file name `grouped-modules.ts` for example, where you want to simply list only the modules and export each one.

```
export {default as clearLineReporter} from '../modules/clear-line-reporter';
export {default as karmaReporter} from '../modules/karma-reporter';
export {default as metaTestReporter} from '../modules/meta-test-reporter';
...
export {default as stdReporter} from '../modules/std-reporter';
export {default as tapJSONReporter} from '../modules/tap-json-reporter';
```

Then in your module you can just do :

```
import * as mods from './grouped-modules'

export {mods}
```

It will export both types and values in a namespace called `s`. You can then import them using :

```
import {mods} from 'your-module'

const anObject: mods.clearLineReporter = ...;
```

This allows you to dynamically group your modules into one variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can reference imported files through some form of reflection?

Answer is dependent on environment, meant in questing, because `import` statement can be ES native modules implementation in browser, or `babel`-ed to require statements in `node.js`, or compile-time resolved bindings in `webpack`.

So, in each case there is solution to do something reflection. In node.js with `babel`-ed code `import` is just `require` wrapper, so any information is available there.

In browser with native ES modules, all requests to them can be served via `ServiceWorker`, so it can provide necessary information about fetched ES modules. Also in browser ES modules can be dynamically imported that way: https://matthewphillips.info/posts/loading-app-with-script-module

Most interesting part is `webpack`: compile-time resolve and semi-reflection can be achieved by `externals` resolver in functional style (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#function), and runtime by load module API ([https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#**webpack_modules**-webpack-specific-](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_modules__-webpack-specific-) )