# exporting imports as a namespace with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, suman

My question is pretty much the same as this one:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4529

Say I have this:

```
//exported imports
export {ISumanOpts, IGlobalSumanObj} from 'suman-types/dts/global';
export {ITestCaseParam} from 'suman-types/dts/test-suite';
export {IHookParam} from 'suman-types/dts/test-suite';
export {IDescribeFn} from 'suman-types/dts/describe';
export {ItFn, ITestDataObj} from 'suman-types/dts/it';
export {IBeforeFn} from 'suman-types/dts/before';
export {IBeforeEachFn} from 'suman-types/dts/before-each';
export {IAfterFn} from 'suman-types/dts/after';
export {IAfterEachFn} from 'suman-types/dts/after-each';
export {DefineObjectContext as IDefObjCtx} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectTestCase as IDefObjTestCase} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectAllHook as IDefObjAllHook} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectEachHook as IDefObjEachHook} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";


export namespace s {

  // ! I want to move all of the above exported items into a namespace here

}
```

Is there a way to use `namespace` or `module` to export things as a part of a namespace instead of individually exporting them?

I have this which is getting close:

[image]

So I tried changing them to imports and then putting them on a const like so:

[image]

But as you can see, some of my declarations are interfaces, not classes, and in that case looks like I get the error message "only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here".

Comment: What you are trying to do is considered not a best practice. Without an explicit namespace, the caller/client can easily add an ad-hoc naming by doing something like this `import * as Suman from '...'`.

Comment: I am looking to use this syntax - `import suman, {s} from 'suman'`, where `s` will have all of the types the user is looking for on it. It will allow for autosuggest, etc.

Comment: Using the suggestion from @realharry the only difference to what you need is everything (including `suman`) would be available under a single alias... `import * as Suman from '...';` you would find `Suman.suman` and `Suman.DefineObjectContext`... it also allows downstream code to depend on less... `import {suman, DefineObjectContext } from '...'`.

Comment: `suman` is too long a variable name, I want a short variable name for the types

Comment: It's also nice to mentally separate the code from the types, `suman` has the runtime code, `s` just has the typings.

Comment: this issue seems to describe the problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4529

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a file name `s.ts` for example, where you want to export everything for your namespace :

```
export {ISumanOpts, IGlobalSumanObj} from 'suman-types/dts/global';
export {ITestCaseParam} from 'suman-types/dts/test-suite';
export {IHookParam} from 'suman-types/dts/test-suite';
export {IDescribeFn} from 'suman-types/dts/describe';
export {ItFn, ITestDataObj} from 'suman-types/dts/it';
export {IBeforeFn} from 'suman-types/dts/before';
export {IBeforeEachFn} from 'suman-types/dts/before-each';
export {IAfterFn} from 'suman-types/dts/after';
export {IAfterEachFn} from 'suman-types/dts/after-each';
export {DefineObjectContext as IDefObjCtx} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectTestCase as IDefObjTestCase} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectAllHook as IDefObjAllHook} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
export {DefineObjectEachHook as IDefObjEachHook} from "./test-suite-helpers/define-options-classes";
```

Then in your module you can just do :

```
import * as s from './s'

export {s}
```

It will export both types and values in a namespace called `s`. You can then import them using :

```
import {s} from 'your-module'

const anObject: s.ISumanOpts = {...}
```

Comment: this seems like my only option at the moment -  I think it's a syntax deficiency in TypeScript, but this solves all the problems in one, so it is only thing that will work, thanks!

Comment: `import`/`export` is an ECMAScript thing. I'm not sure but I think it was made this way for easier resolving of symbols on the browser. Even if TypeScript is compiled it is still a superset of ECMAScript :/

Comment: All these methods are deficient. They basically "fake" namespaces, and without adding extra explanatory comments to code it is not clear that what the code does is assembling a namespace. What is sought is a method to actually define this assembled namespace using the `namespace` keyword. The idea of a namespace having no intrinsic, "own" name and having to be imported under a locally assigned name is outright silly.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is this :

```
import * as Block from './block'
import * as FullNode from './full-node'
import * as ListOnChain from './list-on-chain'
import * as HashTools from './hash-tools'
import * as KeyValueStorage from './key-value-storage'
import * as SequenceStorage from './sequence-storage'
import * as SmartContract from './smart-contract'
import * as NodeBrowser from './node-browser'
import * as NetworkApi from './network-api'
import * as NetworkClientBrowserImpl from './network-client-browser-impl'
import * as NodeApi from './node-api'
import * as NodeImpl from './node-impl'
import * as NodeTransfer from './node-transfer'
import * as NodeNetworkClient from './node-network-client'
import * as WebsocketConnector from './websocket-connector'

export {
    Block,
    FullNode,
    ListOnChain,
    HashTools,
    KeyValueStorage,
    SequenceStorage,
    SmartContract,
    NodeBrowser,
    NetworkApi,
    NetworkClientBrowserImpl,
    NodeApi,
    NodeImpl,
    NodeTransfer,
    NodeNetworkClient,
    WebsocketConnector
}
```

Then in another file, I can import like this, and all will stay in their own space :

```
import * as AllComponents from 'blockchain-js-core'
```

If you want to import them one by one, you can do :

```
import {
    Block,
    FullNode,
    ListOnChain,
    HashTools,
    KeyValueStorage,
    SequenceStorage,
    SmartContract,
    NodeBrowser,
    NetworkApi,
    NetworkClientBrowserImpl,
    NodeApi,
    NodeImpl,
    NodeTransfer,
    NodeNetworkClient,
    WebsocketConnector
} from 'blockchain-js-core'
```

An example can be found here : https://github.com/ltearno/blockchain-js/blob/master/blockchain-js-core/src/index.ts

Answer (score 2):

this was my solution...

```
import { JobEntity as _JobEntity } from '../types';

export namespace JobList {
  export type JobEntity = _JobEntity;
  export interface Props {
    ---------
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).