# import all named exports under their export name without explicitly listing them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, javascript-import

I have a file `modules.js` that exports all `default` exports from my modules by their module name (following [ES6 exporting/importing in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file?rq=1)):

```
export { default as a } from './a/a'
export { default as b } from './b/b'
...
export { default as y } from './y/y'
export { default as z } from './z/z'
```

In my `app.js`, I want to import this module bundle.

I want the exported variables from a...z to be imported from `module.js` so I can use them in `app.js`.

Obviously I don't want to do

```
import { a, b, c, d, ... , x, y, z } from './modules/modules'
```

as that is very verbose and whenever I would add a module in `module.js`, I would also have to change the `import` in  `app.js`.

I've tried

```
import * from './modules/modules'
```

but the variables are not available in `app.js`.

#### Question: How do I simply import **all named exports** *under their export name*?

Example module `./modules/a/a.js`:

```
export default function a() {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this `import m from './modules/modules'` and access the variable as `m.a` or `m.b`... I think it wouldn't cost a lot.

Comment: @Mohit That might not cost alot, but is it not possible to import without the necessity for an owner object?

Comment: There is no additional cost to having a module namespace object from `import * as foo from ...`. In fact, by having it, engines can tell where variables are coming from ahead of time and thus better optimize your code.

Comment: @connexo As far as I know, there is no any possible way of what you are expecting in the current version of ECMAScript 6

Answer (score 5):

Just try import * as sampleModule from './modules/modules'

You can utilize all the exported function from module using sampleModule variable.

`import * as sampleModule from './modules/modules'`

`import './modules/modules'`

Comment: Is it not possible to import without the necessity for a host object?

Comment: its better to use the below code.
import './modules/modules';