# React Native -- Error in multiple class import via index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

I have both **CustomButton** and **InputLabel** classes

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { anycomps... } from 'react-native';
export default class CustomButton extends Component{}
```

and

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { anycomps... } from 'react-native';
export default class InputLabel extends Component{}
```

and in my **index.js**

```
import CustomButton from './CustomButton';
import InputLabel from './InputLabel';

export { CustomButton, InputLabel };
```

and in my **app.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { anycomps... } from 'react-native';
import { CustomButton, InputLabel } from './components';

export default class MyMain extends Component{
   ... code renders here
}
```

my folder structure is:

```
> components
   >CustomButton.js
   >InputLabel.js
   >index.js
> app.js
```

What did I miss or do wrong?

I tried it this way Vue Apps and it worked. Is react native having different implementation for this?

Comment: Did you import { component } from 'react' in every component?

Comment: Yes. Except for index.js

Comment: can you paste also the component where you then use those components?

Comment: updated it @quirimmo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 exporting/importing in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file)

Comment: did you render and return the view inside the component?

Comment: Yes.I've put the render and returned it

Comment: @artiebits, yes i've tried it and it works, but I'm really confused why my solution above won't work as they're just the same since I'm just exporting the default class. Then, in the index I just import and re export it again.