# Export multiple modules from NPM package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a rather large project A using Node and Typescript. In project A I have a lot of different modules that I would like to reuse in another project B.

Therefore I have built the project A with this tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./modules/@types"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

So all the files are built into the /dist folder this way:

- dist

  - moduleA.js
  - moduleA.map
  - moduleA.d.ts
  - moduleB.js
  - moduleB.map
  - moduleB.d.ts
  - ....

To use these moduleA and moduleB in another project, I add the following to the package.json in Project A:

```
    "name": "projectA",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "...",
    "main": "dist/moduleA.js",
    "typings": "dist/moduleA.d.ts",
```

I use yarn workspaces to access Project A as a package in Project B. But problem is that I can only access moduleA, when using `import {ModuleA} from 'projectA'` in my new project B? So how can I access more modules from ProjectA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would simply consolidating all exports in one `index.ts` do the trick for you?

package.json (projectA):

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

index.ts (projectA):

```
// Adjust the relative import paths 
// and identifiers to your structure
export { ModuleA } from "./moduleA";
export { ModuleB } from "./moduleB";
```

Some module in projectB:

```
import {ModuleA, ModuleB} from 'projectA'
```

Comment: see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file

Comment: This does not answer the question. What if you don't want modules included or want to deal with a larger file size?

Comment: I agree. The idea was NOT to export everything via single index.js

Answer (score 9):

I believe what you are looking for is:
https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points

Not clear if TypeScript currently supports it or not:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

It does appear you can work around it though with something like this in your package.json:

```
{
    ...

    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "typesVersions": {
        "*": {
          "dist/index.d.ts": [ "dist/index.d.ts" ],
          "*": [ "dist/*" ]
        }
      },
    "exports": {
        ".": "./dist/index.js",
        "./": "./dist/"
    },

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try `compilerOptions.moduleResolution = 'node16'` in your tsconfig.json

Here's a link to the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution

Comment: @QuantumLicht - where is the link in this answer?