# Exporting "mixed" declarations from .d.ts file - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've got a Typescript project with a .ts file that is exporting some interfaces and a class.
Similar to this:

```
export interface Tree {
  value: string,
  anotherValue: number,
  children: Tree[]
}

export class Utils {
  static adder(val1: number, val2: number): number {
    return val1 + val2;
  }
  [...blabla some static functions...]
}
```

Now I build the project (using basic tsc commands - ES2015 modules as target), and in my /dist there'll be a .d.ts file and a .js file.

In the .js file there won't be any interfaces anymore ofcourse. So it looks like:

```
export class Utils {
  static adder(val1, val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
  }
  [...some more static functions...]
}
```

And in the .d.ts file I have all my interfaces and the declarations for the class, like:

```
export interface Tree {
  value: string,
  anotherValue: number,
  children: Tree[]
}

export class Utils {
  static adder(val1: number, val2: number): number;
}
```

So far so good - everything is looking great.

Now I install my package (/dist folder) into another project and would really like to use my interfaces over there.
So I'm doing this:

```
import {Tree} from "myPackage/dist/myFile"

const myTree: Tree = {someTreeObject}
```

But Typescript will tell me "Cannot use namespace 'Tree' as a type" - why namespace?

A different try:

```
import * as Stuff from "myPackage/dist/myFile"

const myTree: Stuff.Tree = {someTreeObject}
```

But Typescript will tell me "Namespace '"*"' has no exported member 'Tree'."

Then I had a look on some other Typescript declarations and thought "maybe you need to use a namespace" (also the errors sound like that), so I changed myFile to:

```
export declare namespace myFile {
  interface Tree {
    value: string,
    anotherValue: number,
    children: Tree[]
  }

  class Utils {
    static adder(val1: number, val2: number): number {
      return val1 + val2;
    }
    [...blabla some static functions...]
  }
}
```

Trying to `import {myFile} from "myPackage/dist/myFile"` I'll end up with the great "Namespace '"*"' has no exported member 'Tree'." error again.

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong here? I guess it's something really easy but I just don't get it.

Here is a reproduction repo:
https://github.com/schadenn/typescript-problem-repro
Either you can `npm run build` it yourself or just `npm install` the .tgz package and try to `import { NavUtils, TsUtils } from "@test/utils"` and use `NavUtils.ITree` or `TsUtils.Omit<ITree, "label">`.
I also checked in the dist folder so you can see the contents of the package.

Thanks

Comment: The same happens btw for a different file in that I'm just trying to export a single type. `export type Omit<K, P> =... ` - will output an empty .js file and a .d.ts file with my exported type. No luck trying to import that type though. Gives me all the same errors as whrn I try to import the tree interface.

Comment: Do you have types property defined in your package.json of myPackage? Do you link myPackage with `npm link` into your using application?

Comment: Yes I have types set correctly in package.json and no I deployed to a Nexus and did a proper `npm install`. Also I forgot to mention: My "dream" setup would be to have a index.js/index.d.ts that imports and exports all the other modules. But I can't find a best practice on how to export/import types/interfaces/classes - everything I found and tried didn't work.

Comment: You could let typescript emit those declarations with `"declaration": true` and consolidate all exports in one index.ts file, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513973/export-multiple-modules-from-npm-package/57516839#57516839  . Concerning your namespace error, I am not sure, a minimal example would be nice.

Comment: That's what I tried. I'll try to build a repro after my vacation.

Comment: I added a reproduction repo to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the repo, helps a lot. See my answer down under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your types cannot be found, as the package currently uses a wrong `types` path in `package.json`. You can change the `types` field like this:

```
// from
"types": "dist/esm/index.d.ts"

// to
"types": "dist/types/index.d.ts"
```

So it matches the directory you had set for type declaration emissions in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"declarationDir": "dist/types"
```

If you want to use interface `ITree` from package `@test/utils` directly, you can [re-export](https://javascript.info/import-export#re-export) your members. Change your `src/index.ts` like this:

```
// from
import * as NavUtils from "./NavigationUtils";
export { NavUtils };

// to
export * from "./NavigationUtils";
```

In a client, you will then be able to write:

```
import { ITree } from "@test/utils";

// use your interface here
declare const myTree: ITree;
```

Concerning [Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-namespaces): I think, you don't need to use them here:

> Namespaces are simply named JavaScript objects in the **global namespace**. [...]
>   Namespaces can be a good way to structure your code in a Web Application, with all dependencies included as **script tags** in your HTML page.

Comment: Wow. Seems like that was a typical "you're too tired to work, go home" mistake. I changed things around so much that I must've forgotten to change the path at some time. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Sorry. Been glad too early. I updated the repo. There wont be any errors in the IDE when I do `import {TsUtils} from "@test/utils"` but still when I start `tsc`, Typescript will throw `Namespace '"*"' has no exported member Omit`. I'd like to "bundle" my exports from the TsUtils file somehow though (so no `export * from "./TsUtils"`).

Comment: hm, can't reproduce your error atm... Consider that in index.ts you import as namespace TsUtils from "./TsUtils" and then you re-export this namespace. Omit type is the only exported member, so in a client you could write following to use Omit in some way : `import { TsUtils} from "@test/utils"; type T1 = TsUtils.Omit<{}, "">`, which compiles for me. PS: There is also a built in Omit for TS 3.5, so you don't have to define it yourself.

Comment: PPS: in last comment I meant the [JS import namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_entire_module's_contents) (not the TypeScript NS)

Comment: Fixed it. Because you said you can't reproduce the problem I figured it must be some configuration issue - ours is very customized. Not sure why, but we had specified `target: "es5"` but then started tsc in a package.json script with `-m es2015` which doesn't make much sence to me. When I remove the parameter, it wont throw the `Namespace '"*"' has no exported member Omit` errors.