# Import multiple components from one directory

Tags: javascript

I´m importing my components like this

```
import Component1 from "./components/Component1";
import Component2 from "./components/Component2";
import Component3 from "./components/Component3";
...
```

how can I do something like

```
import {Component1, Component2, Component3} from "./components/";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 exporting/importing in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file)

Answer (score 1):

In the `components` folder you can create a `index.js` file. The `index.js` file is automatically loaded when importing a folder.

**components/index.js**

```js
export { default as Component1 } from './Component1';
export { default as Component2 } from './Component2';
export { default as Component3 } from './Component2';
```

**somefile.js**

```js
import { Component1, Component2, Component3 } from './components';
```

above has same result as this (because of file named `index.js`):

```js
import { Component1, Component2, Component3 } from './components/index';
```

Comment: yeah that works too. was looking for maybe a webpack solution. I think is useful but it also could be confusing in cases when you have an index file like your example.

Comment: You could maybe use `alias` with [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) however it depends on the specific use case you're trying to fix. Based on the details available in the question as far as I know there needs to be an `index.js` file.