# Nextjs import export modules in one line

Tags: javascript, babeljs, next.js, es6-modules

I am working on a NextJs app and I have a header folder with a Header.jsx and a default export `Header`.

In the same folder I have a `index.js` with this code

```
export * from './Header'
```

but if I use it, it fails with an error

```
Attempted import error: '../components/header' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Header').
```

If I use this

```
import Header from './Header'

export default Header
```

It works fine. is there a way, in NextJs to use the single line export avoiding this repetition?

Thanks

Comment: your import and export of header looks in the same code block that confuses me a bit, are you saying that you are exporting from other file or import/export from same file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 exporting/importing in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file)

Comment: in next.js components should be exported with export default

Answer (score 2):

## export vs default export

- ES6 provides two ways to export a module from a file: named export and default export.

1. Named Export: (export)

   - you can have multiple named exports in a file

   ```
   // File ./AllComponents.js

   export const Comp1= () => {}
   export const Comp2= () => {}

   //File ./SomeComponent.js
   // ex. importing a single named export
   import { Comp1 } from "./AllComponents";
   // ex. importing multiple named exports
   import { Comp1, Comp2} from "./AllComponents";
   // ex. giving a named import a different name by using "as":
   import { Comp1 as MyCustomName } from "./AllComponents";
   ```

- you can import all of them as one object

  ```
  import * as MainComponents from "./AllComponents";
  // use MainComponents.Comp1 and MainComponents.Comp2
  ```

## Default Export: (export default)

- We can have on ONE default export per file.
- when importing, we have to do as follows

```
// File 1: create and export MyComponent
//create a component
const MyComponent = () => {}
//export it
export default MyComponent;

// File 2: import the component in some File
import DefaultExportFromAComponent from "./DefaultExportFromAComponent";
```

Comment: What I want to do is to use an index file that loads the modules. So Header has its own file, but other components will load it with `./header` since it is exported in the index. So in the index import Header and export it in one single line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file

this might answer your question.