# React import multiple components from a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package, import-libraries

I am trying to import 2 components from the `components` folder. Both components' class are `export default` .

However, I got an error message that I should use the curly braces in my import statement. However, both components above are not using `named export` so curly braces is not needed when importing them.

Why isn't it working? How can I make this work?

Line 4 error
[image: Main app]

[image: Login component]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

as @casimirth stated above since those components are from different files, even though on the same folder, then you need to import them separately as below

```
import Login from "./components/Login"
import Question from "./components/Question"
```

But i think i know what you're looking for, being able to import them all on **one line** right?

below are couple of the ways

**1 .put them all on single file and use `exports`, since in one file only one component can use `export default`**

```
// ./components/componentfile.js
export const Login = () => {...
export const Question = () => {...
```

then where you're using them you can import them as

```
import {Login, Question} from '.components/componentfile'
```

if one of the file is exported with default as below

```
const Login = () => {...
export const Question = () => {...
export default Login;
```

then the using them will be as below

```
import Login , { Question } from './components/componentfile'
```

**2. You wish to keep this two files separately and still import on one line**

then you need to add another file in components file, prefered index.js since if you name a directory without specifying a file, index.js is one being called by default

So, you components directory will have three files,

```
./components
   -index.js
   -login.js
   -questions.js
```

then without editing anything on your login.js,questions.js import them on your index.js and export them from it as below

```
import Login from './login'
import Question from './question'

export {Login, Question}
```

then where you're using them you just import them as below

```
import {Login, Question} from './components' //note with index.js no need to mention //it on import
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `index.js` file in the components folder that imports and exports all the components, then you will be able to import the components at the same line.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072598/es6-exporting-importing-in-index-file) might help you, and the special part is it can performs both import and export using only one single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer like this approach for routes too. It's looks neat and clean.

I'm using following versions mentioned for better clarity

react :  ^18.2.0

react-router-dom :  ^6.4.0

```js
// Pages.js
import Home from './Home'
import Contact from './Contact'
import Login from './Login'
import SignUp from './Signup';

export {
    Home,
    Contact,
    Login,
    SignUp,
}
```

```js
//App.js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { Home, Contact, Login, SignUp } from '/pages'; //  Looks clean


function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/login' exact element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='/signup' exact element={<SignUp />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing them individually:

```
import Login from "./components/Login"
import Question from "./components/Question"
```

Answer (score 1):

To import components in a single

1. create a index.js file inside components folder
2. inside index.js file export all the components

   `export { default as Username } from './Questions';`
   `export { default as PageNotFound } from './Login';`