# Require cycles due to importing from index.js

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am receiving warning on my react-native project:

```
Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. 
Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
Require cycle: src/navigation/index.js -> src/navigation/mainDrawerNavigator.js -> src/navigation/index.js
```

This is because I have a habit of exporting all the classes within a folder from the index.js file, and also importing from the specified index.js file (which is convenient, although I am not sure if it is correct practice, it looks like it is common though: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229947/is-there-any-one-line-analogy-in-es6-for-es5-module-exports-require-inner/32230064#32230064) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard))

I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
   navigation/
      index.js
      mainDrawerNavigator.js
      homeTabNavigator.js
      otherNavigator.js
```

in `index.js` (I am exporting both `mainDrawerNavigator` and `homeTabNavigator`)

```js
export {default as HomeTabNavigator} from './homeTabNavigator';
export {default as MainDrawerNavigator} from './mainDrawerNavigator';
export {default as OtherNavigator} from './otherNavigator';
```

the problem is in `mainDrawerNavigator` I need `homeTabNavigator` thus importing it like this

```
import { 
    HomeTabNavigator,
    OtherNavigator,
} from '@/navigation';  // this is the source of the warning
```

Is there a way to import from `index.js` without causing the `require cycle`?

I know I can import it this way:

```
import HomeTabNavigator from './homeTabNavigator';
import OtherNavigator from './otherNavigator';
```

But for some folders, I have a long list of exports in the `index.js` file and within the folder I wouldn't want to import each one by one (if possible)